# The $n$th prime for large $n$

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers

Is there available somewhere a list of values of $p_n$ for large $n$, where $p_n$ denotes the $n$th prime?  Much like $\pi(x)$ for large $x$ is usually counted for sporadic large values, like powers of $10$, I don't need $p_n$ for all large values of $n$, just for a significant sample of large values of $n$.  Mathematica can only go out to $n = 10^{10}$. OEIS sequence A006988 lists $p_{10^{n}}$ for $n = 1,2,3,\ldots,24$. Basically, my wish is for an analogue for $p_n$ of the tables here for $\pi(x)$: http://www.primefan.ru/stuff/primes/table.html

I am testing some approximations involving the $n$th prime, and to do so I need values of $p_n$ for large $n$.  I need exact values, not approximations, and there aren't enough powers of $10$ to test my approximations.  Incidentally, the Riemann Hypothesis is equivalent to $p_n-\operatorname{li}^{-1}(n) = O(n^{1/2}(\log n)^{5/2}) \ (n \to \infty)$, so computing $p_n$ is not only mathematically nontrivial for large $n$, it is also quite useful.

EDIT: After searching OEIS more, I found $p_n$ for powers of $2$, $3$, and $5$: https://oeis.org/A033844 and https://oeis.org/A038833 and https://oeis.org/A055680.  Also $6$.  Maybe this is enough for me, but it would be great if there were a repository of values $p_n$ for less sporadic values of $n$, as is done for $\pi(x)$.

MORE INFO: A famous conjecture of Montgomery that extends the Riemann Hypothesis implies that $$p_n-\operatorname{li}^{-1}(n) = O(\sqrt{n}(\log n)^t) \ (n \to \infty)$$ for all $t > \frac{1}{2}$.  If you want to test this prediction, then you can't use an approximation of $p_n$.  Rather, you need exact values, or values that you know are within a specified error bound that is verifiably smaller than the $O$ bound above.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131202/discussion-on-question-by-jesse-elliott-the-nth-prime-for-large-n).